# How to display UIImage within UITableView in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have `NSMutableArray *_items`. with 3 properties . label (*text) have tag 1000. image 1001.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL checked;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIImage *image;
```

problem is I can't display an image .

```
_items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
ChecklistItem *item;
item = [[ChecklistItem alloc] init];
item.text = @"Walk the dog";
item.checked = NO;
item.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"];
```

rest of code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"];
    ChecklistItem *item = _items[indexPath.row];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    UIImage *image = (UIImage *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
    image.image = item.image;
    label.text = item.text;
    [self configureCheckmarkForCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `UIImageView` to display images, not a `UIImage`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
```

Also use the `strong` property attribute for those properties, rather than `copy`.

Answer (score 2):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath: implementation you're using UIImage as if it was a view, which it isn't. You probably meant to use UIImageView.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make custom cell class and connect your properties there
and then in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can set those properties

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CustomCell *cell = (AddListTableViewCell *)[tableView
                                                            dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
if(cell==nil)
{
    cell = (CustomCell *)[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
}

cell.myText.text = @"String1"
cell.myUmage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];



return  cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try to save UIImage ?. Just change that property to NSString and save image name.

```
   @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *imageName;
```

Then in your delegate method you can create UIImage with that image name and setImage in a UIImageView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ChecklistItem";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...
        ChecklistItem *item = _items[indexPath.row];
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
        UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item.imageName]];
        label.text = item.text;
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image Here"];
```